# Making a table in react

Tags: reactjs

I have 9 pictures that I want to map right now and make 3x3 table. However, I am not quite sure how I should build the code.

How do I write a code such as "if there are 3 pictures in one row, make a new row"? I'm not sure how the logic should be. I am getting all my data from graphql.

Right now, I have:

```
<div className="feature-images-wrapper col-6">
      <table className="table">
        <tbody>
          {data.allPictures.edges.map(edge => (
            <Pictures node={edge.node} />
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

in tbody tag, I am mapping Pictures component, which is:

```
const Pictures = ({ node }) => {

return (
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div className="feature-image-container">
          <a href={node.picUrl} targer="__blank">
            <img
              className="img-fluid features-logo-img"
              src={node.pic.responsiveResolution.src}
            />
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
};
```

This gives me 9 rows, one picture each row. I feel like there should be a conditional statement to make a 3x3 table with this?? I'm not sure how I should build it.

Help :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can use react-boostrap's grid/row/col.

Below is a sample code I have used to demonstrate 3*3 matrix using grid(react-bootstrap)

    import {Grid, Col, Row} from 'react-bootstrap';

     const renderImages = [...Array(3)].map((val) => {
                return <Row className="show-grid">
                    <br />
                    <Col md={3}>
                        <img src={placeholder} />

                    </Col>
                    <Col md={3}>
                        <img src={placeholder} />

                    </Col>
                    <Col md={3}>
                        <img src={placeholder} />

                    </Col>

                </Row>
            })

            const gridInstance = (
                <Grid>
                    {renderImages}
                </Grid>
            );
```

Finally you can use gridInstance variable to display.

[image]

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. One question though: what does [...Array(3)] represent in the code??

Comment: Array(3) gives the length and adding [...Array(3)] , will enable to iterate. We can also use Array.from({length: 3}), to iterate 3 times.  FYI, Array.from is from ES6.  For more info, please check - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: Thanks John! Helped a lot :)

Comment: Happy to help always :).. happy coding :D

Comment: Thanks :) you too!

Answer (score -1):

Make two new component, Row and Column.
Column : send a image url as props and it should render it.
Row: send array of size three of 3 image url which it will send to 3 Column component.

Now render 3 row component from main component.

This is hardcoding for 3 by 3. You can make it dynamic too. In row component render column component equal no of elements in props.imageUrl.length.

You can use [jsx-control-statements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-control-statements)

Just loop on `props.imageUrl.length`